# How do i get the value of a dic in a json file=?

Tags: python, json

Json file:
(later on I want to add another dic to that file, thats why I gave a name to it)

```
{
    "Highscores":
    {
        "0highscore": 1,
        "1highscore": 5,
        "2highscore": 5,
        "3highscore": 7,
        "4highscore": 8
    }  
}
```

Here I open the file:

```
with open("highscore_history.txt") as Highscore_history_txt:
    highscore_history = json.load(Highscore_history_txt)
    saved_highscores = highscore_history["Highscores"]
```

and here I want to compare the values of the Json file with the value of another value in another file:

```
for v in highscore_history["Highscores"]:
    if v.values() < Highscore_dictionary.get("highscore"):
```

But if I try to start the code I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BinKrassDuFass\PycharmProjects\Snake_beta\main.py", line 794, in <module>
    if v.values() < Highscore_dictionary.get("highscore"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I started with Json yeserday, so I would be glad if you would not just give me the solution, instead I would be happy if you could explain the solution, so that I can solve such a problem next time on my own.

if I print :

```
print(highscore_history["Highscores"].values())
```

I get:

```
dict_values([{'0highscore': 1, '1highscore': 5, '2highscore': 5, '3highscore': 7, '4highscore': 8}])
```

Comment: This is not a `json` problem. When you use: `json.load(...)` you get (in your case) a `dict` referenced by `highscore_history`. Since there is a nested `dict` in there you also get that when you evaluate `highscore_history["Highscores"]`. Now you are iterating over a `dict`. Please look up how to iterate over a `dict`.

Comment: I dont want to iterate over the dic, instead I want to iterate over the values of the dic

Comment: So, did you mean; `for v in highscore_history["Highscores"].values():`? You may not want to iterate over a `dict`, but it will be worth your time to learn because there are many ways to do it.

Comment: does that even make a diffrence=? but yes

Answer (score 1):

Like @quamrana mentioned, one way you can achieve this, is by iterating over the list of values of the dictionary. This may look like:

```py
import json

Highscore_history_txt = '''{
    "Highscores":
    {
        "0highscore": 1,
        "1highscore": 5,
        "2highscore": 5,
        "3highscore": 7,
        "4highscore": 8
    }  
}'''

highscore_history = json.loads(Highscore_history_txt)
saved_highscores = highscore_history["Highscores"]
current_highscore = 7

for score in saved_highscores.values():
    if score < current_highscore:
        print (
            f"""Found historic score smaller than current score."""
            f""" (current: {current_highscore}, score: {score})"""
        )
```